# how i get date month year values in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created meeting page it have two tab bar view one is upcoming and another one is completed meeting so i used where conditions but it take only date but I want date month and year.Here is my code.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream:meeting
      .where("Meeting Type",isEqualTo: type)
     .where("Meeting Date",isLessThanOrEqualTo: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.now()))
      .snapshots(),
  builder:(context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>streamSnapshot){
    if (streamSnapshot.hasData){
      QuerySnapshot<Object?>?querySnapshot = streamSnapshot.data;
      List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot!.docs;
      List<Map>items = documents.map((e)=>{
        "Meeting Date":e['Meeting Date'],
        "Meeting Name":e['Meeting Name'],
        "Place":e['Place'],
        "Time From":e['Time From'],
        "To Time":e['To Time']
      }).toList();
```

When the meeting starts it should be shown in the upcoming page, and after it completed it should be in completed page.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more context on what exactly you want to achieve? You have an array of objects that you want to filter? How do these objects look like?

Answer (score 1):

We have to possibilities here :

**1. Your Meeting Date is stored as a String in your base**

Note that you probably souldn't store time like that and instead use the Timestamp provided by Firestore.

But in this case your `.where("Meeting Date",isLessThanOrEqualTo:` will perform a comparaison between date lexicographically.

So you need a format who will match chronological and lexical order, as `YYYY-MM-DD` (Any year/month/day format will do the trick).

It will probably need to update your existing documents in Firestore to match this.

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream:meeting
                .where("Meeting Type",isEqualTo: type)
               .where("Meeting Date",isLessThanOrEqualTo: DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').format(DateTime.now()))//Use a format who order String in the same order as time
                .snapshots(),
            builder:(context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>streamSnapshot){
              if (streamSnapshot.hasData){
                QuerySnapshot<Object?>?querySnapshot = streamSnapshot.data;
                List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot!.docs;
                List<Map>items = documents.map((e)=>{
                  "Meeting Date":e['Meeting Date'],
                  "Meeting Name":e['Meeting Name'],
                  "Place":e['Place'],
                  "Time From":e['Time From'],
                  "To Time":e['To Time']
                }).toList();
```

**2. Your Meeting Date is stored as a Timestamp in your base**

In this case, not formatting is needed, you can pass the time as is to your query.

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream:meeting
                .where("Meeting Type",isEqualTo: type)
               .where("Meeting Date",isLessThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.now())//Using the Timestamp object provided by the firestore library
                .snapshots(),
            builder:(context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>streamSnapshot){
              if (streamSnapshot.hasData){
                QuerySnapshot<Object?>?querySnapshot = streamSnapshot.data;
                List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot!.docs;
                List<Map>items = documents.map((e)=>{
                  "Meeting Date":e['Meeting Date'],
                  "Meeting Name":e['Meeting Name'],
                  "Place":e['Place'],
                  "Time From":e['Time From'],
                  "To Time":e['To Time']
                }).toList();
```